# That solved my problem is rarely true on Meta

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, meta, wording

On Meta, a lot of duplicate targets  are unanswered, so, while it's a duplicate it doesn't actually solve my problem.

Please could the text on meta be changed to *"Yep, it's a duplicate"* or *"Oops, I made a boo boo"*.

Comment: The dupe hammer got nothing to do with that, message is the same no matter how many users voted to close. And.... guess what?

Comment: @ShadowWizard harumph. It didn't solve it tho :P